# Xamarin DateTime.Today Returns 1970

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin

I'm developing a counter that counts days between present date and given date.

When I'm trying to access `DateTime.Today()` it returns 1/1/1970. My system date is correct.

Error shown below:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you use `DateTime.UtcNow`? `DateTime.Today` relies on the system time zone *and* the system clock - if you use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead, that'll show you whether the problem is with the use of the system clock or with the local time zone.

Comment: When I'm trying to use DateTime.UtcNow and DateTime.Now it returns the same value which is 1970.

Comment: if this is an Android app, the Android emulator maintains it's own clock which may have the system datetime set incorrectly

Comment: Yes, emulator's date is at 1/1/1970 but I can't change it.

Comment: Why can't you change it? Did you go into the Settings app on the emulator and go to the Date & Time settings page? Try turning off the Automatic date & time and Automatic Time Zone and then set manually if the automatic settings are not working.